# Comparing two lists and filtering elements which are in majority in one and minority in another

Tags: python

I have a tree like structure in which at every node a list of 5 documents is attached. Every document has a certain number of words. I want to keep all the words at each node which are present in majority in that node and in minority in other node or in more than 60% document in that node and in less than 40% document in its sibling.

For example: A is the parent node and B,C are its child each having a list of 5 documents attached to it.

```
B = [['a','b','c','d','m'],['b','d','m','n'],['c','d','e','o'],['c','e','f','n'],['b','c','e','g']]
C = [['a','m','n'],['a','m','o'],['b','c','m','n'],['c','n','o'],['b','n','o','g']]
```

So I want to keep b,c,d in B as they are in majority in B and in minority in C and similarly m,n,o in C.
Finally B and C will look like:

```
B = [['b','c','d'],['b','d'],['c','d'],['c'],['b','c']]
C = [['m','n'],['m','o'],['m','n'],['n','o'],['n','o']]
```

Kindly help me how this can be done.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please post your attempts and the blockers encountered.

Comment: Is the number of words in each document equal in 1 node?

Comment: @Jelle Number of words can vary. It may or may not be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion using easily readable code:

```
B = [['a','b','c','d','m'],['b','d','m','n'],['c','d','e','o'],['c','e','f','n'],['b','c','e','g']]
C = [['a','m','n'],['a','m','o'],['b','c','m','n'],['c','n','o'],['b','n','o','g']]

# 1. Retrieve the set of all words
wordSet = set([word for words in B+C for word in words])

# 2. Compute the occurrences of each word in each node
occurB = {word:0 for word in wordSet}
occurC = {word:0 for word in wordSet}
for word in wordSet:
    for document in B:
        if word in document:
            occurB[word] += 1
    for document in C:
        if word in document:
            occurC[word] += 1  

# 3. Filter the nodes using majority and minority
majorityB, minorityB = int(0.6 * len(B)), int(0.4 * len(B))
majorityC, minorityC = int(0.6 * len(C)), int(0.4 * len(C))
newB = [[word for word in document if occurB[word] >= majorityB and occurC[word] <= minorityC] for document in B]
newC = [[word for word in document if occurC[word] >= majorityC and occurB[word] <= minorityB] for document in C]

print(newB) # [['b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'e']]
print(newC) # [['m', 'n'], ['m', 'o'], ['m', 'n'], ['n', 'o'], ['n', 'o']]
```

*Note:

Comparing to your original question, the 'e' is additionnaly kept in `newB`. But I think it is logical because it is in majority in B and in minority in C.*

Comment: I need a little more help from you on the same solution given by you above. I have to implement the same in a tree where at every node I have to compare words of the document with their siblings documents and keep those words at every node having more than 60% count at that node and less than 40% count at its siblings node.  In the original question, if the tree is big and B and C also has childrens and also A has other childs also like D,E then how can this be done. Kindly help me with this. It is very important and urgent for me. Thanks.

Comment: This is not clear enough, moreover it is another question. Please post another question with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added another question. Kindly see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213116/writing-a-recursive-function-to-filter-words-in-a-document-stored-at-every-node