# Writing a recursive function to filter words in a document stored at every node in a tree based on a condtion

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have a tree-like structure where each node has attached a list of 5 documents. Every document has a certain number of words. I want to keep all the words at each node which are present in majority in that node and in minority in other node or in more than 60% documents in that node and in less than 40% documents in its sibling.

For example: A is the parent node and B, C are its children, each having a list of 5 documents attached to it:

```
B = [['a','b','c','d','m'],['b','d','m','n'],['c','d','e','o'],['c','e','f','n'],['b','c','e','g']]
C = [['a','m','n'],['a','m','o'],['b','c','m','n'],['c','n','o'],['b','n','o','g']]
```

So I want to keep b,c,d in B as they are in majority in B and in minority in C and similarly m,n,o in C. Finally B and C will look like:

```
B = [['b','c','d'],['b','d'],['c','d'],['c'],['b','c']]
C = [['m','n'],['m','o'],['m','n'],['n','o'],['n','o']]
```

The above problem have been solved using below code:

```
B = [['a','b','c','d','m'],['b','d','m','n'],['c','d','e','o'],['c','e','f','n'],['b','c','e','g']]
C = [['a','m','n'],['a','m','o'],['b','c','m','n'],['c','n','o'],['b','n','o','g']]

# 1. Retrieve the set of all words
wordSet = set([word for words in B+C for word in words])

# 2. Compute the occurrences of each word in each node
occurB = {word:0 for word in wordSet}
occurC = {word:0 for word in wordSet}
for word in wordSet:
    for document in B:
        if word in document:
            occurB[word] += 1
    for document in C:
        if word in document:
            occurC[word] += 1  

# 3. Filter the nodes using majority and minority
majorityB, minorityB = int(0.6 * len(B)), int(0.4 * len(B))
majorityC, minorityC = int(0.6 * len(C)), int(0.4 * len(C))
newB = [[word for word in document if occurB[word] >= majorityB and occurC[word] <= minorityC] for document in B]
newC = [[word for word in document if occurC[word] >= majorityC and occurB[word] <= minorityB] for document in C]

print(newB) # [['b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'e']]
print(newC) # [['m', 'n'], ['m', 'o'], ['m', 'n'], ['n', 'o'], ['n', 'o']]
```

I want to write a recursive function modifying the above code so that it can be used for the whole tree. Also, number of children at a particular node can be more than 2 i.e. for parent A we can have B,C,D,E,etc children and further B,C,D,E can have their own children in tree. Kindly help how this can be done.

Comment: @Laurent H. : I have posted the question here. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that:

1. the tree is coded through a **dictionary** type
2. for a node with documents, the number of documents per node is always **exactly 5**
3. a word is kept if minority criterion is met for **ALL** the sibling nodes

Here is my suggestion of code, not optimized at all, but it seems doing the job on my side:

```
def RecFilterWords(d):
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            RecFilterWords(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            FilterWords(d)

def FilterWords(d):
    # 1. Retrieve the set of all words
    wordSet = []
    nb = 0
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            nb += 1
            wordSet += [word for words in v for word in words]
    if nb == 1:
        return
    wordSet = set(wordSet)

    # 2. Compute the occurrences of each word in each node
    occur = {}
    for k,v in d.items():
        occur[k] = {word:0 for word in wordSet}
        for word in wordSet:
            for document in v:
                if word in document:
                    occur[k][word] += 1

    # 3. Filter the nodes using majority and minority
    newD = d.copy()

    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            newV = v[:]
            for k1,v1 in d.items():
                if isinstance(v1, list):
                    majority = 3
                    minority = 2
                    if k == k1:
                        newV = [[word for word in document if occur[k1][word] >= majority] for document in newV]
                    else:
                        newV = [[word for word in document if occur[k1][word] <= minority] for document in newV]
            newD[k] = newV     
    d.clear()
    d.update(newD)


# Example with B, C, D as child nodes
B = [['a','b','c','d','m'],['b','d','m','n'],['c','d','e','o'],['c','e','f','n'],['b','c','e','g']]
C = [['a','m','n'],['a','m','o'],['b','c','m','n'],['c','n','o'],['b','n','o','g']]
D = [['b','m','n'],['b'],['g'],['o','b','g'],['b','g']]

# The tree is coded through a dictionary type
d = {"A1": {"B": {"B": B,
                  "C": C,
                  "D": D},
            "C":C
           },
     "A2": {"B":B,
            "C":C}
    }

RecFilterWords(d)
print(d)
# It prints:
# {'A1': {'B': {'B': [['c', 'd'], ['d'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'e'], ['c', 'e']],
#               'C': [['m', 'n'], ['m', 'o'], ['m', 'n'], ['n', 'o'], ['n', 'o']],
#               'D': [[], [], ['g'], ['g'], ['g']]},
#         'C': [['a', 'm', 'n'], ['a', 'm', 'o'], ['b', 'c', 'm', 'n'], ['c', 'n', 'o'], ['b', 'n', 'o', 'g']]},
#  'A2': {'B': [['b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'e']],
#         'C': [['m', 'n'], ['m', 'o'], ['m', 'n'], ['n', 'o'], ['n', 'o']]}
#  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AnkitaPatnaik If this answers suits you well, please accept it.